# ¿Cómo enviar correo usando C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# ASP.NET, el problema es que no envia el correo, he checado muchas veces mi código y no encuentro el problema, pueden ayudarme?

Este código lo tengo en mi clase cs:

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
  public bool enviar(string from, string to,string subject, string body) {
 try
        {
            subject = "solicitud de empleado";
            body = "has recibido una solicitud";
            mail.From = new MailAddress("micorreo@");   
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));   
            //mail.Subject = subject;
            //mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("micorreo@", "passw");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }

      catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    } }
```

Este otro en aspx:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    enviar();

    public void enviar()
    {
        string from = txtbox1.Text;
        string to = txtbox2.Text;
        string subject = TextBox3.Text;
        string body = TextBox4.Text;
    }
        new correo().enviar(from, to,subject,body);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Se genera alguna excepción? En esta línea: `mail.From = new MailAddress("micorreo@"); ` debería ser `mail.From = new MailAddress(from); `. Revisa también las credenciales de correo que usas para enviar los correos.

Comment: @Mauricio-- Ninguna excepción, sólo no llega el correo, también intenté hacerlo así cómo lo escribiste y aun así no lo hace. Para ambos correos son gmail

Comment: Marth, el `Subject` y el `Body` están comentados, descomenta esas líneas e intenta de nuevo. También revisa en la bandeja de salida/elementos enviados de las credenciales de correo. También revisa la bandeja "spam" del destinatario.

Comment: Desafortunadamente no funciona tampoco...

Comment: intentaste enviar el mail desde una aplicacion de prueba pero que sea winforms, pra descartar que el ambiente web no sea la causa

Comment: tambien valida que el mail de destinatario que ingresas es correcto, puede que el mail del "to" no sea valido por eso no llega

Comment: @LeandroTuttini-- No he intentado hacerlo en winform, ya cheque todo y está correcto

Comment: Revisando el codigo es como el que yo utilizo, pero recuerdo que quise utilizar SMTP de google, tuve que dar permisos en la cuenta de gmail. https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es

Comment: Tenia el mismo problema, cambie el puerto al 465 y listo eso fue todo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verifica que estas usando `System.Net.Mail`, porque hay otro: `System.Web.Mail` que ya anda en desuso.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("tucorreode@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Código extraído desde: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336/3613462

Comment: Si lo tengo System.Net.Mail, caray no sé que está pasando, he checado en spam, bandeja y nada llega

Comment: @MarthA. como dice Leandro en su comentario: ¿comprobaste si escribiste bien los correos?

Comment: @Mauricio--Si, los correos están exactamente iguales..

Comment: @MarthA. prueba el ejemplo que ilustra el usuario fredyfx en su respuesta y dinos los resultados.

Comment: @MarthA. ¿No tienes algún Firewall que esté bloqueando la salida del correo? o en su caso, ¿algún puerto que esté cerrado?

Comment: He ahi el problema no puedo ver nada de eso lo tengo bloqueado por parte del trabajo, checaré esto, gracias

Comment: @fredy recién protegí la pregunta porque está atrayendo a muchos usuarios con problemas para conectarse a gmail... Quizás sería bueno agregar más info en la respuesta para cubrir esos casos problemáticos, mencionando qué puertos tiene gmail para conectar por SSL y cuándo/cómo hay que habilitar "enviar a través de aplicaciones inseguras"

Answer (score 1):

que tal amigo a ver te cuento: lo que yo hago es que en el webconfig poner los datos de la cuenta del correo de donde vas a mandar  los mensajes (correo saliente)

```
<!-- Para envio del correo de recuperacion de contraseña-->
<add key="AdminUser" value="horacio.xochitemol@gmail.com"/>
<add key="AdminPassword" value="***********"/>
<add key="SMTPName" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
<add key="SMTPPort" value="587"/>
```

bien ahora para mandar el mensaje lo hago de la siguiente forma.

```
public static async Task SendMail(string to, string Subject, string body)
    {
        var Mensaje = new MailMessage();
        Mensaje.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        Mensaje.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUser"]);
        Mensaje.Subject = Subject;
        Mensaje.Body = body;
        Mensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credencial = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUser"],
                Password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"],
            };

            smtp.Credentials = credencial;
            smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
            smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(Mensaje);

        }
```

cual es la idea aqui que desde el webconfig pueda cambiar la cuenta de correo saliente.

te comento que también tienes que configurar gmail para que permita conexión desde otras aplicaciones.

saludos.