# ¿Alguna forma de envíar correos por Outlook sin tener instalada la aplicaion en el equipo? C#

Tags: c#, email, consola, outlook

me gustaria preguntarles si hay una manera de enviar correos por Outlook sin que tenga que instalar la aplicacion ya que anteriormente utilice Interop Outlook y todo estaba perfecto hasta que intente ejecutar mi aplicacion en un servidor y me marcaba este error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Estuve investigando y basicamente es porque deberia de instalar Outlook en mi servidor pero yo no tengo los permisos para hacerlo y la unica manera de arreglar esto es buscando otra manera de enviar el email, pido sus consejos y opciones para saber que puedo hacer, gracias!

Comment: No deberias usar outlook para enviar correos, deberias usar un servidor SMPT, outlook es un programa, que se conecta a un servidor... porque tu programa no hace lo mismo?

Comment: La verdad no tengo idea de como hacer eso, si me pudieras ayudar con un ejemplo te lo agradeceria mucho :)

Comment: No es un ejemplo... es todo un proceso...c# tiene una clase basica para el envio de mails (system.net.mail) pero no se que necesitas. te diria que leas sobre las siguientes cosas... como se envia un mail, servidores SMTP.. tu programa, va a hacer exactamente lo que hace outlook...

Comment: Teóricamente es posible enviar un correo desde cualquier aplicación utilizando los protocolos correctos, en la práctica esto ya no es posible por asuntos de SPAM y necesitas un servidor de correos que haga de intermediario, por lo que debes desarrollar es un cliente que conecte con tu servidor e ingresar los datos necesarios para dicha conexión (mismos datos con los que configuras otros clientes como Outlook). Aquí un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47005/301324

Comment: Ya estuve investigando e intente usar codigo que hay en unas paginas pero no me funcionan, no hace nada y se queda congelada la pantalla... por ahora solamente quiero enviar un correo con lo que sea pero que se envie correctamente, si me pudieras apoyar amigo :v

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Usa MailKit https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit